# Handle transaction rollback when procedure2 is called inside procedure1

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, commit, rollback

I have two separate stored procedures, the second one is called in try block of first stored procedure.

First procedure skeleton code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure1]
-- Parameters
@procedure1_parameter

AS
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN

  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  BEGIN TRY

  EXEC [dbo].[Procedure2] @procedure2_parameter;

  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH

  SELECT
    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
    ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    END

  END CATCH;

  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END
```

The second procedure skeleton code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure2]
-- Parameters
@procedure2_parameter

AS
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN

  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  BEGIN TRY

  -- Procedure2 code 

  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH

  DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
  DECLARE @ErrorLine INT;
  DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT;
  DECLARE @ErrorProcedure NVARCHAR(200);
  DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
  DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

  SELECT
    @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
    @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
    @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
    @ErrorProcedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
    @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),
    @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();

  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

      RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,
      @ErrorNumber,
      @ErrorSeverity,
      @ErrorState,
      @ErrorLine,
      @ErrorProcedure
      );
    END

  END CATCH;

  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END
```

As you can see, they have almost same code, except the second one has error raised in catch block. Should first procedure catch error raised from second procedure if second procedure fails? Is this proper way to handle transaction rollback/commit when we have second stored procedure call inside try block of first stored procedure?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I'm using sql-server.